# Live name Availability check with Ajax and Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel-5

I am having problem to check live name of product from `products` table of `name` column. I need help. I got `checking...` message only but not got `OK` or name `not available message`. Is somethig wrong in my query

my ajax

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$("#name").change(function() { 

var usrN = $("#name").val();

if(usrN.length >= 4)
{
$("#status").html('<img src="images/loadingAnimation.gif"> Checking ...');

    $.ajax({  
    type: "POST",  
     url :"{{action('Product\ProductController@Check')}}", 
    data: "name="+ usrN, 
    success: function(msg){  

   $("#status").ajaxComplete(function(event, request, settings){ 

    if(msg == 'OK')
    { 
        $("#name").removeClass('object_error'); 
        $("#name").addClass("object_ok");
        $(this).html('<img src="images/success.png" align="absmiddle"> OK<');
    }  
    else  
    {  
        $("#name").removeClass('object_ok'); 
        $("#name").addClass("object_error");
        $(this).html(msg);
    }  

   });

 } 

  }); 

}
else
    {
    $("#status").html('<font color="red" style="margin-left:125px;">something went wrong <strong></strong> .</font>');
    $("#name").removeClass('object_ok'); 
    $("#name").addClass("object_error");
    }

});

});


</SCRIPT>
```

my controller

```
 public function Check(Request $request)
    {

    $product= new Product;  
    $name = $request->get('name');  
    $product->name = $request->get('name');


    $query = \DB::table('products')->select('name')
             ->where('name','=',$name)
             ->first();
        if($query)
        {
            echo"name not available!";
        }
        echo"name available!";
    $product->save();
```

my form

```
<input type="text" name="name" id="name" style="margin-top:35px;" />
<span id="status"></span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are checking on client site the following:

```
if(msg == 'OK')
```

But you never sent that string from server and also use `return` instead of `echo`. The following may solve your problem but still it's not something I would use or recommend but anyways:

```
// In your check method
if($query)
{
    return 'error';
}

$product->save();

return 'ok'; // ok is lower case so use if(msg == 'ok')
```

Don't use `echo`. Please read the [Laravel](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1) documentation first and also [check this](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) and find how you can use `JSON` data type as response.

---

*Always use exact `version` when taging.*